# Inconsistent ultraThinMaterial background in SwiftUI sheet

Tags: ios, swiftui

**Description:**

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI application inspired by Apple Maps, where I have a primary sheet on the home view with a background set to `.ultraThinMaterial.` The sheet works well most of the time, but I'm encountering an issue where, especially when opening the `CarDetailsSheet`, the `.ultraThinMaterial` background is not consistently applied, and a white background appears instead (randomly).

```swift
// Code for presenting the primary sheet
.sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
    BottomSheet()
        .presentationDetents([.medium, .large, .height(geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom + 32)])
        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
        .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial)
        .interactiveDismissDisabled()
}

// Code for the BottomSheet
struct BottomSheet: View {
    // ... (omitting some code for brevity)

    // Sheet for presenting details
    .sheet(item: $selectedCar) { car in
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            CarDetailsSheet(car.id)
                .padding()
                .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial)
        }
    }

    // ... (omitting some code for brevity)
}
```

I've tried various approaches, such as adjusting the order of modifiers and removing unnecessary background modifiers, but the issue persists. Specifically, when opening the CarDetailsSheet, it sometimes comes with the proper ultraThinMaterial background, and sometimes it comes with a white background.

[image: expected background]
[image: background showing instead]

This is the logged message when dismissing `CarDetailsSheet`:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2838ed3b0 'accessoryView.bottom' _UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x131448960.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x13d61f7c0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28383d9a0 'assistantHeight' SystemInputAssistantView.height == 45   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x13d61b0e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2838c30c0 'assistantView.bottom' SystemInputAssistantView.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x13d61f7c0.top   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x13d61b0e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2838c2bc0 'assistantView.top' V:[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x131448960]-(0)-[SystemInputAssistantView]   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x13d61b0e0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2838c2bc0 'assistantView.top' V:[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x131448960]-(0)-[SystemInputAssistantView]   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x13d61b0e0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this inconsistency would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Information:**
Xcode version: 15.1 (15C65) 
iOS version: 17.2

Answer (score 0):

hey I had the same problem and i end it up fixing it by just doing it the old way creating an extension of view: inside the extension put this func:

```
    func blurredSheet<Content: View> (_ style: AnyShapeStyle, show: Binding<Bool>, onDismiss:
                                  @escaping ()->(), @ViewBuilder content: @escaping ()->Content)->some View{
    self
        .sheet(isPresented: show, onDismiss: onDismiss) {
            content ()
                .background(RemovebackgroundColor())
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill (style)
                        .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .all)
                }
            
        }
}
```

also you will need this:

```
    fileprivate struct RemovebackgroundColor: UIViewRepresentable{
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiview: UIView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            uiview.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```

use it like a normal sheet: .blurredSheet(.init(.ultraThinMaterial), show: $showSheet){content view} you can delete the callback dismiss  in the extension function or not if you need it"). hope it helps, good luck.